# iOS6 toggle WiFi on non-jailbroken device

Tags: ios, ios6, wifi, iphone-privateapi

I am developing an in-house iOS application (**NOT FOR APPLE STORE**, so I am happy to go for private API) and I would like to be able to toggle the wifi on or off programmatically. The reason for why I want to do this is that with some WiFi routers whenever the internet connection is interrupted it happens that iPad is not able to restore the WiFi - toggling the WiFi on/off solves the problem however.

After searching around for a day on SO and Google I could not find any recent posts. Is it possible on iOS 6, **without jailbreaking the device**, to toggle the WiFi on/off with private APIs. Does anybody have source code he could share?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same situation/problem.

Comment: No not yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I think it make sense to look at **SystemConfiguration.framework**.

It has set of API to work with different connection interfaces, which are defined [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SCNetworkConfiguration/Reference/reference.html):

However, to be clear, it's just a guess. I am not sure whether these API's will allow to turn wifi on/off.

Comment: I was looking into this as well.